# multiple item lookup text box

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

i have created an access 2010 search box that filters results based on a column within a table and then presents me with the results based on query.

what i am trying to achieve is to be able to put not just one item at a time in the search box but multiple items.
this is for a whole estate of routers that i manage and every day i get a list of routers that need to be status checked so what i am doing now is copying and pasting each router name on the search box and it gives me the status, location and circuit ref but what i want to do i to copy and paste all of the router names in one go and get independent results for each router.

this is the code that i have applied for the filter in the text box:

```
Where Condition = [Circuit Reference] Like "*" & [Forms]![Query1]!  [Text12] & "*"
```

i could add more text boxes and apply this filters to them but i would still have to copy and paste every router name independently.

i am not an access guru so appologies if this question is too easy to answer but i cant find anything on the web that helps me with my issue.

Comment: Why not use a combobox as a filter ? If you have all router references within a table that's a good way.

Comment: that wont do the trick i think @LostReality as i need to be able to copy and paste up to 20 router names and get independent results for each within the form.

Comment: What do you mean "independent" results? Do they all need to be wildcard searches? What kind of string do you want to paste in? comma delimited, space, new line, tab?

Comment: @Brad they will be new line searches. And BTW thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want multiple wildcard searches on the same field. You can do this by using `OR` in your SQL query.

```
Dim strSearchConditions As String
Dim strTerms() As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim i as Integer

strSearchConditions = ""

strTerms = Split(Me.txtSearch,",") 'Assuming you separate your search terms with a comma

For i = 0 To UBound(strTerms)
    If Not strTerms(i) = "" Then
        strSearchConditions = " OR [Circuit Reference] Like '*" & strTerms(i) & "*'"
    End If
Next i

If Not strSearchConditions = "" Then
    strSQL = "Select * FROM tblMyTable WHERE 1=1 AND (" & strSearchConditions & ")"
Else
    MsgBox "No search terms!"
End If
```

Comment: i do want multiple wildcards but the terms are not going to be coma separated, they are each on a new line and the result of each wildcard search has to show up on the form.
so to explain things better:
i want to enter 20 different router names each on a differnent line of text.
and when i hit the "find" button i want the form to display the "hostname", "status" and "bandwidth" of router1.
then below that i needs the same results but for router2.... and so on...
what i am getting now is just the result for one item at a time.

Comment: That does not change anything except the `Split` function from the solution above. Instead of a comma, look for a line feed. Try replacing "," with `Chr(13) & Chr(10)`, `vbCrLf` or `vbNewLine` (no quotes) in the above code.